# inet or inet6 in freebsd

Tags: c, networking, freebsd, ifconfig

I am trying to get network interface information from 
[struct ifaddrs](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/9/ifaddr/)

How can I determine if the interface I am looking at is of inet (ipv4) or inet6 (ipv6)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You test the `ifa_addr->sa_family` - it will be `AF_INET` for IPv4 addresses, and `AF_INET6` for IPv6 addresses.

You can then cast the `ifa_addr` member to either `struct sockaddr_in *` or `struct sockaddr_in6 *` as appropriate.

Comment: just found this out! Thanks much.

Comment: would you be knowing how can I check if interface address is assigned "static"ally or via dhcp?

Comment: @hari: No, I suggest you ask another question for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489916/freebsd-network-interface-address-dhcp-or-static

Answer (score 0):

In FreeBSD, assuming you've got kernel support for both, the question of IPv4 vs IPv6 is just a matter of configuration.

The "GENERIC" kernel in FreeBSD includes the "INET6" option, which gives you IPV6.  If you haven't rebuilt your kernel and *excluded* that option, then you have IPv6 on any interface simply by configuring an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to open an IPV6 socket on the interface to see if it supports IPV6.